# How to connect to this database where the url starts as "jdbc:as400//..."

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-midrange, db2-400, jtopen

I am working on a project where I have to fetch data from a database. I found from the db properties in eclipse, that the url is starting as "jdbc:as400//...". Is there any way other than using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries. I am using visual studio 2012 to build a windows application.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzahh/jdbcdrvr.htm

Comment: Can I use the drivermanager class in c#. Isn't it a java class

Comment: Sorry I didn't check that, I just assumed that being an IBM product it should have support on their site.

Comment: No problem. Any idea do i need to have ibm i access for Windows installed if I am using drivermanager class.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `DriverManager` uses JDBC, so if you need a JDBC driver for IBM i, you can retrieve JTOpen from [sourceforge](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/). The driver file in there is `jt400.jar`.

Comment: That was helpfull @jmark. If I switch to java platform and use drivermanager with jdbc driver, do I still need to install "ibm i access for Windows" on my pc. 
Since the i access is a paid software and may needs the end system to be installed, I am not willing go that way.

Comment: I use jtopen does not require i access.